# How to use like operator for remove whitespace and similar words at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, sql-like

Below is my query from which I'm excluding some characters from query. It's working for me.

```
SELECT
  b.TRANS_DETAILS_ID,
  b.DEBIT_AMOUNT,
  b.ENTITY_NAME,
  REPLACE(b.DESCRIPTION, 'SP Z O.O.', '') AS DESCRIPTION,
  DATE_FORMAT(a.TRANSACTION_DATE_TIME, '%d-%m-%Y') AS TRANS_DATE
FROM bank_book_transaction_master a,
     bank_book_transaction_details b
WHERE a.TRANSACTION_DATE_TIME
BETWEEN '$from_date_srch' AND '$to_date_srch'
AND DEBIT_CREDIT_FLAG = 2
AND a.ORG_ID = '$org_id'
AND a.BANK_ID = '$bank_id'
AND a.TRANSACTION_ID = b.TRANS_MASTER_ID
```

But my problem is in my database `SP Z O.O.` these characters are storing differently sometimes. In some columns it's `SP Z O.o.` or `sp z O.O.` or `SP Z   O.O.`. My query removes only if charaters are similar like `SP Z O.O.`.   But I want to add all conditions like small letters whitespace etc.

I tried with `LIKE %SP Z O.O.%` but it shows me result in 1 and 0.

Comment: Huh?  Can you us some tabular sample data you currently have along with a second table for how it should be?

Comment: What's the character set and collation of your `DESCRIPTION` column in your `bank_book_transaction_details` table? I bet it's case-sensitive. Show us your table defintions, please.

Comment: its case insensitive